# add keys and values from input method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a task and I did almost of it, but I'm stuck in how i will add keys and values into dictionary from user I think that I have to use `input`   method but I'm not sure .

This code is what i done it shows the max value and key but i add the dictionary i want something like this

```
x= {'omar':20,'nagy':5}
maxKey= max(x, key=x.get)
maxValue=max(x.values())
print maxKey,maxValue
```

but the user is the one who enter the key and value

Comment: `input()` sounds feasible, although `raw_input()` is probably better for Python 2. Have you any code to show what you're having trouble with? What's the actual problem? What is the input format?

Comment: can you edit your question to add what you are trying to achieve and what code you have written so far?

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do:

```
count=2
x= {}
while count:
    name=input('name:')
    value=int(input('value:'))
    x[name]=value
    count-=1

maxKey= max(x, key=x.get)
maxValue=max(x.values())
print maxKey,maxValue
```

which will result in:

[image]